# Calculate mean by group using dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm practicing dplyr package using famous dataset from ggplot2, 'diamonds' data. 
I am trying to calculate mean 'price' of diamonds grouped by variable 'cut'.
My code is as following.

```
price.cut <- diamonds %>%
group_by(cut) %>%
summarize(Mean = mean(price, na.rm=TRUE))
```

My expectation is to get mean price grouped by 'cut' variable. However, I only get one value, the total mean of price.

```
>price.cut
   Mean
1 3932.8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The reason could be that we accidentally loaded the `plyr` library.  There is a `summarise` in that package as well

```
diamonds %>%
    group_by(cut) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(price, na.rm=TRUE))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#        cut     Mean
#      <ord>    <dbl>
#1      Fair 4358.758
#2      Good 3928.864
#3 Very Good 3981.760
#4   Premium 4584.258
#5     Ideal 3457.542
```

---

If we use the `plyr::summarise`

```
diamonds %>% 
   group_by(cut) %>%
   plyr::summarize(Mean = mean(price, na.rm=TRUE))
#    Mean
#1 3932.8
```

Comment: Thank you very much akrun! It works well and problem is solved :)

Comment: @akrun will `%>%` work without using `magrittr` or `dplyr`? As you're using `dplyr::summarize` (not loading a package)

Comment: @PoGibas `magrittr` is loaded via namesapce though I haven't specificallly loaded it